# Looking for a book with the cover of a girl with bright blue eyes, purple/pink hair, and nose ring

Tags: story-identification, novel, powers

When I was 12 (around 2010) I read this book about these kids who went to a regular school but went to a certain class once a day because they had special powers. 
I believe it was a series and all of the books were in a different person's point of view.

In the one I read they talked about a kid in the class who never talked and no one knew his power and then at the end of the book the main girl found her Dad but he was a bad guy or something.

I'm 18 now so I don't remember a lot about this book but I have a sketch of the cover because I liked the girl in the cover with her bright blue eyes, purple/pink hair, and nose ring, but I can't find the book anywhere and don't remember the name of it.

Comment: Was it possibly Charlie Bone? I'm not confident enough to post an answer...

Comment: No it wasn't but thank you!

Comment: Hello Kayley, welcome to [scifi.se] and thank you for your question. If you remember any additional details, you can [edit] your question to add them. Meanwhile, have you taken the [tour] yet?